# Pipe a command to pv but hide all the original command's output

Tags: bash, pipe, pv

I'm trying to use `pv`, but I want to hide the command I piped in's output while still be able to see pv's output. Using `command &> /dev/null | pv` doesn't work (as in, pv doesn't receive any data). `command` produces output on both standard output and standard error, and I don't want to see either.

I tried using a grep pipe (`command &> /dev/null | pv | grep <=>`) but that now and then outputs things to the terminal.

Comment: Although it didn't do as i expected, it still didn't hide the original command's output. 'command | pv' I want to hide 'command' 's output and still see 'pv''s output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`man pv` says](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

> To use it, insert it in a pipeline between two processes, with the appropriate options. Its standard input will be passed through to its standard output and progress will be shown on standard error.

The output you see comes from `pv`. The progress bar is on stderr, and the content you piped in is on stdout. You can redirect the output:

```
cmd | pv > /dev/null
```

and you will still get the progress bar output.

If the command produces *its own* text on stderr as well, you can [redirect that explicitly to `/dev/null`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), before passing on the output to `pv`:

```
cmd 2>/dev/null | pv > /dev/null
```

Comment: I'll try out them all and return what works for me.

Comment: 'cmd 2> /dev/null | pv > /dev/null' works for me. Thanks.